# Binomial/Geometric/Bayes perspectives on coin tosses?

Tags: statistics, bayesian, binomial-distribution

[image]?

So I have the following question which I am trying to figure out/verify answers.

**a)** I used the binomial probability mass function with n= 10 and p = 0.5 to determine the values. I think a success can be thought of as getting a head, as denoted by k. So I got,

$$P( k = 5 ) = 0.24609375 \qquad P( k = 10) = 0.0009765625$$

Is this approach correct ?

**b)** For this part, I calculated $P( X > 1 )$ by doing the following:

\begin{align}
P(X > 1 ) &= 1 - P ( X = 1 ) \\
&= 1 -  0.5 ( 0.5 ) ^ { 1 - 1 }  = 0.5
\end{align}

For $P( X > 10 )$, how would I calculate that. Would it be simply $1 - P(X = 10)$ or do I have to add up all the probabilities up $X = 10$, as in:

$$P( X > 10 ) = 1 - [ P( X = 1) + P ( X = 2) + \cdots + P( X = 10 ) ?$$

**c)** I have very little idea on what to do here since the $p > 1/2$ which is not an exact number.

I am also trying to understand how calculating these values help me settle the dilemma. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Part B is not correct.  $P(X>1) = 1-P(X=1)-P(X=0)$.  $P(X=n)$ needs to be calculated including the 10 throws.

Comment: I don't understand, X=0 doesn't make sense for geometric random variable.